# Sort Records in Original Order After UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My question seems to have been worded poorly the first time around, so this is my attempt to explain it more clearly + provide table structure and data below.

Please consider table dt:

```
Create Table dt
(LogID Int Not Null Identity Primary Key, StartTime DateTime, EndTime DateTime)

Insert Into dt(StartTime,EndTime)
Values 
    ('2019-07-31 07:00', '2019-07-31 7:30'),
    ('2019-07-31 06:30', '2019-07-31 07:00'),
    ('2019-07-31 12:00', '2019-07-31 13:15'),
    ('2019-07-31 7:30', '2019-07-31 12:00'),
    ('2019-7-31 05:30', '2019-07-31 06:30')
```

| LogID | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-07-31 07:00:00.000 | 2019-07-31 07:30:00.000 |
| 2 | 2019-07-31 06:30:00.000 | 2019-07-31 07:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2019-07-31 12:00:00.000 | 2019-07-31 13:15:00.000 |
| 4 | 2019-07-31 07:30:00.000 | 2019-07-31 12:00:00.000 |
| 5 | 2019-07-31 05:30:00.000 | 2019-07-31 06:30:00.000 |

I'm trying to come up with a query that would return

- each record twice, once with StartTime and once with EndTime as EventTime
- Order by EventTime and then by StartTime first, EndTime second.

Desired result:

| LOGID | EVENTTIME |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 31/07/2019 5:30 |
| 5 | 31/07/2019 6:30 |
| 2 | 31/07/2019 6:30 |
| 2 | 31/07/2019 7:00 |
| 1 | 31/07/2019 7:00 |
| 1 | 31/07/2019 7:30 |
| 4 | 31/07/2019 7:30 |
| 4 | 31/07/2019 12:00 |
| 3 | 31/07/2019 12:00 |
| 3 | 31/07/2019 13:15 |

I have tried

```
Select 
LogID, StartTime As EventTime, 'Start' As EventType from dt
Union All
Select LogID, EndTime, 'End'from dt
Order By
EventTime ASC, EventType Desc
```

But the order is not correct

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot the time values into a column (along with a description of each in another column). That would give you the two new columns, `EventTime` and `EventType`, but also keep all the original columns accessible. As a result, you would be able to sort the resulting set first by `StartTime`, then by `EventTime`, while limiting the output columns only to those required:

```
SELECT
  dt.LogID
, et.EventTime
, et.EventType
FROM
  dt
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    VALUES
      (StartTime, 'Start')
    , (EndTime  , 'End'  )
  ) AS et (EventTime, EventType)
ORDER BY
  dt.StartTime ASC,
  et.EventTime ASC
;
```

This way you do not need to use a derived table, nor do you need to hit the source table more than once.

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=2bf3c000734738b83c8f330823be5028) for a live demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
select LOGID, DESCRIPTION, STARTTIME Time from T
union all 
select LOGID, DESCRIPTION, ENDTIME from T
order by LOGID, Time
```

If you want to order the event pairs by STARTTIME instead of LOGID, then

```
with q as
(
    select LOGID, DESCRIPTION, STARTTIME, STARTTIME Time from T
    union all 
    select LOGID, DESCRIPTION, STARTTIME, ENDTIME Time from T
)
select LOGID, DESCRIPTION, Time
from q
order by STARTTIME, Time
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be neglecting to add a label to your new transformed dataset. You can ignore this if you are rigorously certain that all data in the base set conforms to your expectations, but my instinct would be to create a new dataset like so...

```sql
create table events ( 
    EventId       int identity not null primary key,
    LogID         int          not null references [log] (LogID),
    [Description] varchar(100),
    EventTime     datetime2(0) not null,
    EventType     varchar(10)
);

insert into events (
    LogID,
    [Description],
    EventTime,
    EventType
)
select 
    LogID as EventID,
    [Description],
    StartTime as [EventTime],
    'Start' as [EventType]
from [log]
union all
select 
    LogID as EventID,
    [Description],
    EndTime as [EventTime],
    'End' as [EventType]
from [log];
```

Which you can sort on LogID and EventTime giving a result set like so.

```
+---------+-------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| EventId | LogID | Description        | EventTime           | EventType |
+---------+-------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|       1 |     1 | Travel to new site | 2019-07-31 05:30:00 | Start     |
|       6 |     1 | Travel to new site | 2019-07-31 06:30:00 | End       |
|       2 |     2 | Meeting            | 2019-07-31 06:30:00 | Start     |
|       7 |     2 | Meeting            | 2019-07-31 07:00:00 | End       |
|       3 |     3 | Presentation       | 2019-07-31 07:00:00 | Start     |
|       8 |     3 | Presentation       | 2019-07-31 07:30:00 | End       |
|       4 |     4 | Travel to new site | 2019-07-31 07:30:00 | Start     |
|       9 |     4 | Travel to new site | 2019-07-31 12:00:00 | End       |
|       5 |     5 | Setup              | 2019-07-31 12:00:00 | Start     |
|      10 |     5 | Setup              | 2019-07-31 13:15:00 | End       |
+---------+-------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Consider the linked [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10d9f336e28b9a6577b4769ab4cd7847)